# Mouse gestures or keyboard shortcuts for navigating forward/backward in the documentation center

Tags: front-end, documentation

Is there any way to get gestures (e.g. trackpad- or Magic-Mouse-swiping left/right) to work for navigating forward and backward in the *Mathematica* help browser, particularly on a Mac? If not, what are the keyboard shortcuts to navigate forward and backward?

Comment: I've been playing around and can't seem to find any keyboard shortcuts for this either. If there are keyboard shortcuts, you could use something like BetterTouchTool to implement the functionality... but so far, I can only see the toolbar buttons.

Comment: Yeah, I'm flummoxed after trying a bit more - this is a good question. FWIW, this is why I use the [reference centre in my browser](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/Mathematica.html) for Mathematica help.

Comment: @ian.milligan: Perhaps I should ask if there's a way to rebind the F1 key to a search of the web reference center, rather than the internal help?

Comment: @Isaac Hmm, indeed. I would try to find a rebinding option in OS X myself, but I wonder if Mathematica has a workaround.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the help page [`ref/menuitem/DocumentationCenter`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/menuitem/DocumentationCenter.html), the keyboard shortcuts to navigate one page backward or forward in Mathematica for OS X are <kbd>⌘</kbd> <kbd>[</kbd> and <kbd>⌘</kbd> <kbd>]</kbd>
(or alternatively <kbd>⌥</kbd> <kbd>⌘</kbd> <kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>⌥</kbd> <kbd>⌘</kbd> <kbd>→</kbd> ), so you could use a third-party app like for example [MagicPrefs](http://magicprefs.com/) to bind those keys to a trackpad gesture.

For the sake of completeness, the corresponding shortcuts on Windows & Linux systems are <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>→</kbd> respectively.

Comment: Unfortunately, those shortcuts do not work when the cursor is in an input cell, or in the search bar.

Comment: In response to the comment by Hector, I am using Mathematica 13.0.0.0 and the shortcuts given in this answer work in both cases.