# "Go back" and "Go forward" in help?

Tags: keyboard, documentation

This is a duplicate question with [Gestures for forward/backward in help browser (particularly on a Mac)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1382/gestures-for-forward-backward-in-help-browser-particularly-on-a-mac). Please close this question.

In IE, we can "go back" by <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>, and "go forward" by <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>.

This would be very helpful in *Mathematica* help. Is it supported?
[image: screenshot of Mathematica help]

Jim

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the justification for asking a question about this here rather than just trying it for yourself. The answer is yes.

Comment: To be perfectly clear, the privilege of asking questions here is no substitute for experimenting on your own, and searching the docs.

Comment: At the very least, search this site first (use Google with the `site:` operator).

Comment: @rm-rf this question is not exactly a duplicate, since it works by default on Windows. Still, the question should be closed, and I won't quibble about the reason.

Comment: @Oleksandr, at the very least, Heike did mention the shortcuts in her answer to the other question...

Comment: To All,
I sincerely apologize. I will do more homework before asking new questions.

Comment: May I oblige with another quite trivial question? If I click my username(profile), then click "Questions" (the left-most button on the upper right area of the page), I can only see counts for {votes, answers, views} but not the number of comments. I missed several comments because cannot see the counts. 

Is there any way to see the count for comments?

Comment: @0x4A4D I found it, in "Profile" page >> responses, I can see all {all, revisions, comments, answers}.